# counting similar consecutive bits in vhdl

Tags: algorithm, vhdl, fpga, counting

I have a 8192-bit array coming in 512-bit in each cycle and I need the count of each batch of similar consecutive bits.

for example: if I have the array [0000_111_00_1111] the answer would be [4,3,2,4]

I am thinking of using for loop but as it is a big array I am afraid that it will slow the design. Is there any smart way to do this VHDL?

Comment: No, looping though all element is the smartest way. It will achieve the task in `O(n)` time, where `n` is your array's size. Since you need to access all the data in the array to return your result, there cannot be a faster algorithm.

Comment: @m.raynal If you loop through the array, in code it will take 0 time. No pipelinine or memory is specified.

Comment: @AhmadZaklouta Please give more specifications? is this for synthesis or just a simulation? what have you tried so far? What problems are you having?

Comment: @Tricky this is for synthesis. the data is coming 512 bit a time. I tried for loop so far and it is working but I am afraid when I integrate this module into the system I will have a timing issue. So I wonder if there were a smarter algorithm than just looping.

Comment: a loop will just create a massive asynchronous chain and be terrible. You need to draw out the circuit before writing any code. Have you drawn the circuit that you expect?

Comment: Is there an upper-bound (lower than 512) how long each "batch of similar consecutive bits" can be? or is any value up to 512 possible?

Comment: @MrSmith42 any value is possible. they could all be one or zero. I need to know the count and the index for each batch.

Comment: maybe I can use reduction AND operator to test first if it is equal to 0 or 2**512 and if not i loop. I wonder what is the hardware realization for reduction AND operator?